# In Excel how to create multiple rows from a single data row

Tags: sql, excel

I have an execl datasheet with data looking like this

```
id  desc        part no 1      Qty 1   part no 2   Qty 2   part no 3    Qty 3   
1   PartsName   382A012-3-0 3       382A023-3   3       382A012-25   3
```

And need it to look like this

```
id  desc           part no          Qty
1    PartsName     382A012-3-0       3
1    PartsName     382A023-3/42-0    3
1    PartsName     382A012-25/86-0   3
```

This from a SQL Table so I could do it in SQL if that makes it easier

Anybody any suggestions as how to best to sort this?

Comment: It will be a lot easier to parse text in SQL.  You should post the table structure.

Comment: I agree that should be done in SQL And I did have quick look at this But the Generating SQL is already fills a sheet of paper from some 20 joins to unnormalizes the table and I got lost in the code.

So a I ended up doing it all in excel by creating a row per part number and then sorting to remove null and then sorting to group them by ID.

As this was a one off it looked like less work than debugging the SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make a `UNION` in the SQL

```
SELECT id, desc, partNo, qty FROM parts 
UNION SELECT id, desc, partNo2 as partNo, qty2 as qty FROM parts 
UNION SELECT id, desc, partNo3 as partNo, qty3 as qty FROM parts 
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t have the option of using SQL and need to use Excel.  You can use the TRANSPOSE function. It is an array type function so you need to use the {}.  If you haven´t used it before I recommend reading the help first.  I however don´t think you can use transpose to get it exactly as you describe it.  The id and desc column have to handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add next formulas on a new sheet:

```
column A=MOD(ROW()+1,3)
```

it's like a skeleton :)

First row is headers

```
column B
=IF($A2=0,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,0),COLUMN()-2),B1)
```

autofil col C with it

```
column D
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,0),COLUMN()+CHOOSE($A2+1,-2,0,2))
```

autofil col E with it

one more - your datasheet is "sheet1"